# .onchange not consistently picking up changes to input

Tags: javascript, html, input, onchange

When I make a change to the input type="number" id="homevalue" it does not fire a change until I change another input. All the other inputs fire a change right away, and I cannot see any difference that would explain this:

```
<body style="font-family: arial;">

  <form name="repaymentcalc" action="">
    <div align="center">
      </br>

      <p>
        Home Value £
        <input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" style="width: 75px">
      </p>

      <p>
        Loan Amount £
        <input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px">
      </p>

      <p>
        Interest Rate
        <input type="number" id="interestrate" value="3.00" style="width: 50px">%
      </p>

      Term
      <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 100px">
      <div id="years" style="display:inline-block;">25 years

      </div>

      <div id="repayments">Monthly Repayment: £948.42</div>
      <p>
        <div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>

    </div>
  </form>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
      document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onchange = repayment;
      document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = repayment;

    }

    function repayment() {

      var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
      var y = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.value * 100, 10) / 120000;
      var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
      var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

      var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

      var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

      var year = z / 12;

      document.getElementById("repayments").innerHTML = 'Monthly Repayment: £' + repayment.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById("ltv").innerHTML = 'Loan to Value: ' + loantovalue.toFixed(1) + '%';
      document.getElementById("years").innerHTML = year + ' years';

    }
  </script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `jQuery blur` event

Comment: you could try onkeyup.  also you are not using jquery so there is no need for that tag (unless you want to use it)

Comment: Try setting the event handler on the `onkeyup` event for that element instead.

Comment: You have not set the onchange event for the homevalue. You can see a wokring demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714309/onchange-not-consistently-picking-up-changes-to-input/32714573#32714573)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason  it never executes, was because you are missing.

```
document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
```

[Code Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/8c4z36aw/)

Answer (score 0):

You try this,

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = repayment;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look to use `oninput` instead with a number input. `onchange` will only fire when using the native number selectors within a number type.

See the following snippet where I've included both types of event handler;

```js
(function(){
  var inp = document.querySelector('input'),
      logChange = function() {
        console.log('there was a change');
      },
      logInput = function() {
        console.log('there was input'); 
      };
  
  inp.onchange = logChange;
  inp.oninput  = logInput;
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <input type="number">
</body>
```

I think in this case `oninput` may be a better solution for you. `oninput` will fire upon each input and not when the input loses focus like it would with `onchange`. There is a short note about this [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> **onmouseup** event is also needed if values are being changed by mouse clicks. User can change the value either by clicking on arrow buttons or by putting keyboard input, in below example both the cases are handled.

```js
 window.onload = function() {
   document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onkeyup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onkeyup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onkeyup = repayment;

   document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onmouseup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onmouseup = repayment;
   document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onmouseup = repayment;

 };

 function repayment() {
   console.log("Here");
   var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
   var y = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.value * 100, 10) / 120000;
   var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
   var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

   var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

   var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

   var year = z / 12;

   document.getElementById("repayments").innerHTML = 'Monthly Repayment: £' + repayment.toFixed(2);
   document.getElementById("ltv").innerHTML = 'Loan to Value: ' + loantovalue.toFixed(1) + '%';
   document.getElementById("years").innerHTML = year + ' years';

 }
```

```html
<form name="repaymentcalc" action="">
  <div align="center">
    </br>

    <p>
      Home Value £
      <input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" style="width: 75px">
    </p>

    <p>
      Loan Amount £
      <input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px">
    </p>

    <p>
      Interest Rate
      <input type="number" id="interestrate" value="3.00" style="width: 50px">%
    </p>

    Term
    <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 100px">
    <div id="years" style="display:inline-block;">25 years

    </div>

    <div id="repayments">Monthly Repayment: £948.42</div>
    <p>
      <div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/a61vk3ah/)**

It is not triggering because you have not defined `onchange` event for `homevalue`. You can add like below.

```
window.onload = function() {
      document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
      document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
      document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onchange = repayment;
      document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = repayment;

    }
```

Also, `homevalue` has big value, it actually changing but not affecting due to precision. I have changed homevalue on demo and you can try fully working demo.